# Retrieving and Saving Large Number of Messages from AWS SQS DLQ to CSV Using Boto3 API

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sqs

How can I retrieve a backup of approximately 50,000 messages from an AWS SQS Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) and save them to a CSV file using the Boto3 API? I have tried using the receive_message method, but it seems to only retrieve up to 10 messages at a time. Can anyone provide me with a code snippet that can fetch all the messages in one go?

i did tried using the receive_message method and encountered the limitation of retrieving only up to 10 messages at a time but i have to take all messages from DLQ in single go

Answer (score 1):

It is [not possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) to retrieve more than 10 messages in one request.  You would have to create a loop in your code.

Comment: can I iterate over messageId?

Comment: In my case I know total message count and simple bash + aws cli command store 1.7k messages for me, but you should think about visibility timeout option. --- for COUNT in $(seq 1 170)
do
    echo $COUNT
 aws sqs receive-message --queue-url \
https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-secret-deadletter \
--attribute-names All --message-attribute-names All --max-number-of-messages 10 \
--visibility-timeout 600  >>my-secret-deadletter-count_$COUNT.txt
done